# How is python's float.__eq__ implemented in the language?

Tags: python, math, floating-point

I know that the best way to compare two floats for equality is usually to use `math.isclose(float_a, float_b)`. But I was curious to know how python does it if you simply do `float_a == float_b`.

I suppose it's implemented in C, but what is the logic behind it ?

Comment: `math.isclose(float_a, float_b)` is not "the best way to compare two floats for equality". It is *a way* to compare two floats for something *kind of like* equality, which may sometimes but not always be an appropriate operation to perform.

Comment: Are you actually curious to know **how** Python implements the comparison, that is, to understand the code or algorithm or uses, or are you curious to know **what** function the comparison performs, that is, a specification of the results. Regarding the latter, my recollection is that `==` tests for equality: It returns true if and only if the left operand is the same number as the right operand, without any allowance for rounding errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the [source code for float object comparisons](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/660592f67c0d825b06eb4a38ccc04b34a1f01f00/Objects/floatobject.c#L362)

Essentially. It looks super complex, but that complexity is mostly in handling the case where a `float` is compared to an `int` (`int` objects in Python are arbitrarily sized, they aren't C-int's wrapped in a Python object).

But for the simple case of `float` and `float`:

```
static PyObject*
float_richcompare(PyObject *v, PyObject *w, int op)
{
    double i, j;
    int r = 0;

    assert(PyFloat_Check(v));
    i = PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(v);

    /* Switch on the type of w.  Set i and j to doubles to be compared,
     * and op to the richcomp to use.
     */
    if (PyFloat_Check(w))
        j = PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(w);
```

So it just creates two C `double`s from the `float` objects, then (skipping all the int handling stuff):

```
 Compare:
    switch (op) {
    case Py_EQ:
        r = i == j;
        break;
    case Py_NE:
        r = i != j;
        break;
    case Py_LE:
        r = i <= j;
        break;
    case Py_GE:
        r = i >= j;
        break;
    case Py_LT:
        r = i < j;
        break;
    case Py_GT:
        r = i > j;
        break;
    }
    return PyBool_FromLong(r);
```

It just does a C-level `==` comparison, ultimately. So it does *not* do `math.isclose(float_a, float_b).` underneath the hood.